# Close flap of navigator using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

again me.
I use the following code to open a new flaps on the navigator:

```
function openNewWindowWithPost(url, params) 
{
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  form.method = 'POST';
  form.action = url;
  form.target = '_blank';
  for (const key in params) 
  {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
    {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'hidden';
      input.name = key;
      input.value = params[key];
      form.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

It works very fine, but now I wish to close those flaps created with this code using javascript, I dont know how can I do it.

I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There's nothing you can do after `form.submit()`, the form will be submitted, and the page server responses with is loaded. All the old script is gone, it can't be executed anymore.

Comment: If you were to use AJAX to send the data to the server rather than a regular form your options for closing new tabs (flaps?) would be greater

Comment: What does "close those flaps created" mean? What is a flap? Is it a window or a tab? You can edit your question to make that more clear.